# Getting Error When Uninstalling Google Chrome

Tags: uninstall, google-chrome

I can't update or uninstall Google Chrome. I am getting this error:

```
Setting up google-chrome-stable (36.0.1985.125-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I remember changing and replacing default icons of Google Chrome before. How do I solve this?

Comment: This is a problem with Google's packaging, so you should probably report it to them.

Comment: I really don't think so. I guess something messed up when I replaced chrome's default icons. I guess that's the reason why it can't be updated/uninstalled. Do you know any way to force uninstall chrome? @dobey

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Thanks but same error @Tim

Comment: What about uninstalling from software centre or synaptic?

Comment: I also get a problem uninstalling package error :( @Tim

Comment: Okay, `sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome`

Comment: Same error @Tim

Comment: Sorry, I've run out of ideas. finally: `sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome*`

Comment: @Tim: If there's an error in the packaging scripts, it can NOT be resolved through `apt`, Synaptic, or the Software Center. It will have to be through `dpkg`.

Comment: The postinst script of the package is passing the wrong arguments to a program it requires. That is a problem in the package.

Comment: I managed to solve it by reinstalling it first ;)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the error and the mention of `post-installation script`, I would say that even the installation didn't complete successfully. You'll have to run `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all google-chrome-stable` to remove it.

Edit: Run `gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.postinst`, and add a `#` in front of any lines that call `xdg-icon-resource`. Save it, and try removing the package again.

Comment: Removing google-chrome-stable (36.0.1985.125-1) ...
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
xdg-icon-resource: size argument must be numeric
Try 'xdg-icon-resource --help' for more information.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still returns with error @Saiarcot895

Comment: Apparently, even `dpkg` has to run the scripts and make sure there are no errors. You might have to modify the scripts.

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure how to do that.. @saiarcot895

Comment: Edited. I'm assuming you use/are familiar with `gedit`. If you would rather use a command-line tool, replace the command as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was installing the xdg-utils package, removing chrome, and removing the xdg.utils package once it all finished:

1. yum install xdg-utils
2. yum remove google-chrome
3. yum remove xdg-utils

Comment: Same here. On ubuntu, running `apt install xdg-utils -y` solved the issues for me.

Answer (score 1):

The response [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/messed-up-dpkg-google-chrome-stable-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-4175498370/) helped me,

It's very similar to @saiarcot895, except I also had to modify `/var/lib/dpkg/info/google-chrome-stable.prerm` in the same way.